# can someone tell what you browse on a hotspot

Tags: hotspot

if you are using a mobile hotspot and the mobile hotspot you are connected to is using data can the history you browse on the device that is using the hotspot be seen by the device that is the mobile hotspot?

Comment: very simply, yes

Comment: I think your question could be more simply rephrased: do hotspots log traffic?

Comment: do they?????????

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/37597/how-to-use-public-wifi-safely

Comment: @daddy I'm not sure why you are surprised by an answer of 'yes' when you asked a yes or no question.

Answer (score 2):

If you're connecting to pages over HTTPS, they can only see the domains of what you visit. So if you're on `https://www.example.com/cats`, they will know you're on example.com, but not that you're on the cats section.

However, if you're only using HTTP to connect (so `http://www.example.com/cats/Oskar`), they can know you're looking at the cat Oskar, as well as any content transferred if they decided to capture it.

Of course, HTTPS isn't necessarily 100% protected, end of story, since it could be poorly configured on the website with weak algorithms or misconfigured.

Now, I don't believe your standard mobile hotspot has traffic logging, but that doesn't mean they can't! If you're concerned about a non-technical person snooping, you're probably fine, but it's totally possible for someone with know-how. When in doubt, browse with caution.